# Custom sidebar/sub navigation

Tags: navigation

Unfortunately I'm still struggling to get to grips with Sharepoint 2010, I've created a master page which I'm actually really happy with, and the top navigation etc works nicely with dropdowns, but the **left side navigation** is causing me issues.

At the moment on most pages it just has:

```
Libraries
- Site pages
Contact Us
```

That's if I'm lucky. **Most pages just have no side navigation at all**. Although a few random pages do have relative and sub-content listed.

I was tempted to try and add this in via Sharepoint designer (and I probably will for the right sidebar that I need to add) but then it'd be completely static and not change per page, also it'd obviously make it impossible to **add items via the front end**.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, quick launch menu is displayed using *AspMenu* control.

In default master page this control is placed inside *UIVersionedContent* control and is declared as follows:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu id="V4QuickLaunchMenu" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" DataSourceId="QuickLaunchSiteMap" UseSimpleRendering="true" UseSeparateCss="false" Orientation="Vertical" StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" SkipLinkText="" CssClass="s4-ql" />
```

To find out what's wrong with the quick launch menu, you should check your master page for existance of a control with such signature (id="V4QuickLaunchMenu"), and compare its contents and position within the masterpage with the original master page file (v4.master).

Comment: Many thanks, I'll take a look at this tonight - cheers for pointing me in the right direction (by the way, I can't voteup yet, sorry!)